# Sequentialising Google Sheets Macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-crawler

I'm looking for a way to recursively generate links to next pages on a website with canonical structure. In essence, I'm trying to generate a link to each next page and then feed that result back in to the process to find the following page ad infinitum. However, I'm having problems automating this as the macro seems to be trying to generate the result for cells that are empty (i.e. the results for an earlier cell hasn't been created/copied yet).
So I'd like to sequentialise the macro to start from A20, generate the result for that cell, copy that result to A21, then begin the macro again for A21, et cetera, without requiring constant human input.
The Google spreadsheet with the error can be seen [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k3uLN5ub9lNPPbR6O9o3fRNNjjB5IvRpRGUUta3r4dM/edit#gid=958618279) in cell C27 and the macro itself can be seen [here](https://script.google.com/macros/d/Mexq4uYyEPtfEFyS2N-syxXltwiXuWJZZ/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvGxnw-kyALSHO3EM_f0PQcBDDmGroTXML1Cg6A6pTMncTJvvAJKnhg4r2pKpllDV5a9ucOp326VWec1B_3CFy_98oxT17DyzM4T_M0Pu_7_ydJuOEgxY0nlHUh0m47HH7tLAVlhKQE).

I realise this may be quite a roundabout way to perform this task and am open to any suggestions that may be easier, more intuitive, or faster.

Answer (score 0):

So two suggestions: one is that with stuff that is a continuous scroll, its very easy to find the json of the source, and either grab all the data you want in one go, or by easily picking out the "next page" or pagination...

I personally use importdata() and importxml() more than any other functions, and when in google sheets I also use regexextract() and regexreplace() when needed.

for example the json your looking for is here: http://iconosquare.com/controller_nl.php?action=nlGetMethod&method=mediasTag&value=cricket&max_id=1145408330912313787

if you look at the top row, it tell you what the next min and max is so technically you could just extract that piece to generate your url.

Second option is to just build the query such that it autoincrements the urls. I can give you an example, but I would like to understand a little more about what you really want in the end result...

Are you just looking for the pagination urls, or are you wanting to extract the actual data from them?